# ¿como puedo hacer para que no me salga el error: "store is not defined"?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Tengo un conjunto de botones en los que cada vez que presiono alguno me sale el error: "ReferenceError: store is not defined".

El siguiente fracmento es la parte del codigo donde dice que esta el error, pero no lo veo.

```js
add: () => store.commit('add'),
add2: () => store.commit('add', 2),
addThreeAsync: () => store.dispatch('addThreeAsync'),
subtract: (payload) => store.commit('subtract', +payload)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya encontre el error:

```js
add: function(){
      this.$store.commit('add')
      },
  add2: function(){
      this.$store.commit('add', 2)
      },
  addThreeAsync: function(){
      this.$store.dispatch('addThreeAsync')
      },
  subtract: function(payload){
      this.$store.commit('subtract', +payload)
      }
```

El problema estaba en que tenia que reemplazar el signo "=>" por un "function() {}". Y en "store" tenia que escribir antes "this.$store".